# fwrite doesn't seem to copy the whole file (just the start)

Tags: c++, file-io, fopen, fwrite

I'm trying to make a exe program that can read any file to binary and later use this binary to make the exact same file.

So I figured out that I can use `fopen(content,"rb")` to read a file as binary,
and using `fwrite` I can write block of data into stream. But the problem is when I `fwrite` it doesn't seems copy everything.

For example the text I opened contains `31231232131` in it. When I write it into another file it only copies `3123` (first 4 bytes).

I can see that it's a very simple thing that I'm missing but I don't know what.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
long getFileSize(FILE *file)
{
    long lCurPos, lEndPos;
    lCurPos = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, 2);
    lEndPos = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, lCurPos, 0);
    return lEndPos;
}

int main()
{
    //const char *filePath = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Digital10\\MyDocuments\\Downloads\\123123.txt";
    const char *filePath = "C:\\Program Files\\NPKI\\yessign\\User\\008104920100809181000405,OU=HNB,OU=personal4IB,O=yessign,C=kr\\SignCert.der";


    BYTE *fileBuf;          
    FILE *file = NULL;      
    if ((file = fopen(filePath, "rb")) == NULL)
        cout << "Could not open specified file" << endl;
    else
        cout << "File opened successfully" << endl;
        long fileSize = getFileSize(file);
        fileBuf = new BYTE[fileSize];
        fread(fileBuf, fileSize, 1, file);
        FILE* fi = fopen("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Digital10\\My Documents\\Downloads\\gcc.txt","wb");
    fwrite(fileBuf,sizeof(fileBuf),1,fi);


    cin.get();
    delete[]fileBuf;
    fclose(file);
    fclose(fi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Enclose the else clause in `{` and `}`. Indentation does not determine blocks in `c++`. Otherwise your code will crash if you fail to open the file.

Comment: You are not programming in C, you are using C++. The way you use the `<<` operator to do output is 100% C++. I've re-tagged the question.

Comment: @unwind Despite few couts this is definitely C question.

Comment: @user3125367 Because of 'a few couts' this cannot possibly be anything but a C++ question.

Comment: @EJP And now C people not interested in C++-only question will miss it.

Comment: really sorry made you guys confused. I learned c and C++ both a little bit made it a strange mixture.

Comment: @user3300378 If you want to ask a 'C' question make sure that's what it is.

Comment: @EJP the problem is that people who ask are not interested/aware of your last requirement. And those who are interested will definitely miss the whole discussion. That's the strange result of a great idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
fwrite(fileBuf,fileSize,1,fi);
```

You did read `fileSize` bytes, but are writing `sizeof(...)` bytes, that is size of pointer, returned by `new`.

Comment: fileSize was the problem why I couldn't copy everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A C++ way to do it:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("Source.txt");
    std::ofstream out("Destination.txt");
    out << in.rdbuf();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have swapped the arguments of `fread` and `fwrite`. Element size precedes the number of elements. Should be like so:

```
fread(fileBuf, 1, fileSize, file);
```

And

```
fwrite(fileBuf, 1, fileSize, fi);
```

Also address my comment from above:

Enclose the else clause in `{` and `}`. Indentation does not determine blocks in c++. Otherwise your code will crash if you fail to open the file.

EDIT: and the another problem  - you have been writing `sizeof(fileBuf)` bytes which is constant. Instead you should write the exact same number of bytes as you've read. Having in mind the rest of your code you could simply replace `sizeof(fileBuf)` with `fileSize` as I've done above.

Comment: that was a very shameful mistake. Thanks you for finding that out.

Comment: That is not why only 4 bytes were written :)

Comment: yup. but still a shameful mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
        fileBuf = new BYTE[fileSize];
        fread(fileBuf, fileSize, 1, file);
        FILE* fi = fopen("C:\\Documents and Settings\\[...]\gcc.txt","wb");
    fwrite(fileBuf,sizeof(fileBuf),1,fi);
```

`fileBuf` is a pointer to `BYTE`. You declared it yourself, look: `BYTE *fileBuf`. And so `sizeof(filebuf)` is `sizeof(BYTE *)`.

Perhaps you wanted:

```
fwrite(fileBuf, fileSize, 1, fi);
```

which closely mirrors the earlier `fread` call.

I strongly recommend that you capture the return values of I/O functions and check them.